# Writing failed when using remote Kafka schema_registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

My code implemented for writing Avro data through Schema_Registry server to Kafka broker. The local test is good`(I setup a local Broker and Schema_Registry server)`. but when I changed my configuration file and used the remote kafka and schema_registry server, the writing failed because of the TimeoutException. `(but when I logged in the remote server and used Avro producer/consumer command line, it works good too. )`

Do I need to change any configuration in Schema_Registry side or in my client side?

My schema_registry sever properties file as following:

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081
kafkastore.connection.url=localhost:2181
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=fals
```

My producer code as following:

```
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.5.149.21:9092");//this is a remote ip
props.put("schema.registry.url","http://10.5.149.21:8081");
```

Comment: Are you able to access http://10.5.149.21:8081/subjects?

Comment: yes, I can access it.

Comment: From the same computer running the Java code? If so, then I believe there should be no TimeoutException. Can you provide the full stacktrace?